# Spring Webflux HttpResponse

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

```
class Test{
    public Mono<ServerResponse> test(ServerRequest req){
        Mono<String> data = Mono.just("test");
        System.out.print(data);
        return ServerResponse.ok.body(data, String.class);
    }
}
```

When the client makes a request, "MonoJust" is printed at line 4,
but "test" is returned in the Http Response Body.
I know that a publisher doesn't produce data before a subscription, so why does the Http Response contain "test" not "MonoJust"?

Answer (score 4):

This behaviour might look a bit odd because you've just used `Mono` to wrap an actual value - but this is not what reactor (and reactive frameworks in general) are designed for.

Remember that `Mono` is a *publisher* which may or may not emit an element in the future, not just a wrapper for a given value. When you return `ServerResponse.ok.body()`, you're explicitly stating that you want the body to contain the result emitted by the publisher that you're passing in - the method then returns another publisher, `Mono<ServerResponse>`, that publishes the required server response when your `data` publisher emits a value.

`System.out.print` on the other hand is implicitly calling the `toString()` method on `Mono`, which needs to produce a value *now*, without blocking or waiting (it's returning a `String` after all, not a `Mono<String>`.) It can't print the value since it won't necessarily be there, so instead it just prints the name of its class (`MonoJust` in this case refers to the fact you've instantiated the `Mono` with `Mono.just()`.)